# Is it possible to load demo data automatically after I upgrade/install a module?

Tags: odoo

I want to odoo to create/update the demo data every time if i install/upgrade a module.

And Is it possible or any workround to implmenet this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

When we install the module, it executes all files listed in the manifest file. And when we upgrade the module, it skips demo files to load. So the *data* attribute is important in your situation.

Data/Odoo tag attribute with noupdate="0" and noupdate="1" will decide to create/update xml content. noupdate="1" will freeze the xml content.

You can try this:

Create a demo file / normal xml file. Inside the manifest file, declare in the `data` attribute not in the `demo` attribute.

Optional: Data/Odoo tag declared with noupdate="0".